# String Substitution Problems

Tags: c++, string

I'm having trouble with a program I'm trying to compile. It's a string substitution program.

It's supposed to replace the first **first** with **second**, every **all** with **some**, then the very last **last** with **penultimate**.

When compiling, I get the errors "Run-Time Check Failure #0 - The value of ESP was not properly saved across a function call. This is usually a result of calling a function declared with one calling convention with a function pointer declared with a different calling convention."

> Unhandled exception at 0x7697C42D in ConsoleApplication6.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: std::out_of_range at memory location 0x0031F6E0.

Then I get a debug error saying `CRT detected the application wrote to memory before start of heap buffer.`

Does anyone have a clue as to what I did wrong?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    string data, textOut;

    ifstream dataIn;
    dataIn.open("indata.txt");

    if (dataIn.is_open()) {
        while (dataIn.good()) {
            getline(dataIn, data);
            cout << data << endl;
        }
        textOut = data;
        while (dataIn.is_open()) {
            textOut.replace(textOut.find("first"), 6, "second");
            textOut.replace(textOut.find("all"), 4, "some");
            textOut.replace((textOut.find_last_of("last", 0)), 5,
                            "penultimate");
        }

        dataIn.close();
    } else
        cout << "Unable to open file. Please confirm you have exact file name "
                "and location." << endl;

    ofstream fileOutput;
    fileOutput.open("dataout.txt");
    fileOutput << textOut;
    fileOutput.close();

    system("pause");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your `while` loop conditions are bad.  You shouldn't use `good()`, it doesn't do what you expect.  Also, I'm not sure how your second loop would ever end.

Comment: `while (dataIn.is_open())` should be an infinite loop

Comment: The error say exactly what you are doing wrong, writing before the begin of a buffer. By the way, you are sure you are calling the right `replace` function. All overload that receive an **iterator**, receive a **second iterator** too (the end of the substring to substitute)

Comment: I'm a pretty new person at programming, so I have little idea what in the nine hells I'm doing. This is the first time I've ever hit something like this. Can you give a little more information, @NetVipeC?

Comment: When you used the debugger, which line is causing the issue?

Comment: It starts on line 23 with my first textOut.replace line. I can't figure out how to fix it. @ThomasMatthews

Comment: See the first and second edits of my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is confusing.  Let me try to figure out what you are doing.

```
while (dataIn.good()) {
    getline(dataIn, data);
    cout << data << endl;
}
textOut = data;
```

The above code loops until an error occurs, printing all of the text.
The variable `data` will have the last text line in it.

You then proceed to read the file, in it's error state, in the next loop:

```
   while (dataIn.is_open()) {
        textOut.replace(textOut.find("first"), 6, "second");
        textOut.replace(textOut.find("all"), 4, "some");
        textOut.replace((textOut.find_last_of("last", 0)), 5,
                        "penultimate");
    }
```

The file will remain open until it is closed, so this is a `forever` loop since there are no statements to close it inside the loop.

Also, since `textOut` is a copy of `data`, which was the last line of text in the file, you are replacing the text in `textOut` until something closes the file.

Notice how you don't reinitialize the `textOut` variable with new content in the loop.

Finally, at the end of your program (should somebody close the file), you write the `textOut` variable, which is the transformed last line of the input text, to the output file.

Also, you check the status of opening the input file but you don't check the status of opening the output file.

What are you trying to do?

### Edit 1: transforming text from a file

If you were transforming or editing lines in a text file, here's how it might be performed:

```
while (getline(dataIn, data)) // Read until no more data
{
  cout << data << "\n";

  // Transform or edit the "data" text
  std::transform(data.begin(), data.end(), data.begin(), toupper);

  // Write out the data to the output file
  dataOut << data << "\n";
}
```

A primary difference in design is that processing is performed a line at a time.  One text line is read in, printed, transformed and written to an output file.  A new text line is read in and processed.  This is repeated until there is no more input data.

### Edit 2: Replacing data

I suggest you stay away from the LISP syntax and call one function at a time.  This will allow you to check return codes and process them before passing the return value as the parameter to another function.

For example, the `std::string::find` function returns a position in the string of the found text, ** or std::string::npos if the search text was not found**.

So, let's first find the text and verify it exists before replacing:

```
std::string::size_type position = 0;
position = textOut.find("first");
if (position != std::string::npos)
{
  // The text "first" was found, now replace it.
}
```

Using the information about [std::string::replace](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/replace), we'll use the "position, length" variation.

```
std::string::size_type position = 0;
const std::string key_text("first");
position = textOut.find(key_text);
if (position != std::string::npos)
{
  // The text "first" was found, now replace it.
  std::string::size_type length_of_key_text(key_text.length());
  textOut.replace(position, length_of_key_text, "second");
}
```

Comment: It's supposed to replace this string with the replacement words above.    
"This is the first time I ever ate ice cream.  I wish I was the first person who ever ate ice cream.
    The very last time I ate ice cream, it gave me a headache.  I swore it would be the last time.
    All I ever do is eat, eat, eat ... all the time.  We all eat too much all the time."

It then is supposed to write the replacement to the other file (dataout.txt)
I've removed the while (dataIn.good()) bit, because I was told it wasn't good practice to use it.

I'm working on trying to end the loop as we speak.

Comment: ...Comments don't show spacing. Looks very jumbled written like that. Bothersome.